# Show Button only to Site Administrator

Tags: ssom

I have a asp.net button , And I would like to show only to sharepoint site administrator using Server Object Model.

Can any one help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

For SSOM, you can use the SPUser.IsSiteAdmin from SPContext:

```
if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin)
{
    // hide the asp button
}
```